# MySQL Sorting on two subsets

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to figure out a way to essentially sort on a couple of different subsets of a table. Imagine these two tables:

```
City
id  name
1   ACity
2   BCity
3   CCity

Project
id  name    type    city
1   AP      0       ACity
2   BP      1       ACity
3   CP      1       BCity
4   DP      1       CCity
5   EP      1       ACity
6   FP      0       CCity
```

What I want is to display all the cities that have at least 1 project of type 0 to be listed first. All the projects in that city are listed, with projects of type 0 at the top (and then sorted alphabetically). Any cities without projects of type 0 are then displayed alphabetically afterwards. So for this example, the results would be:

```
Desired result:
ACity   AP
        BP
        EP
CCity   FP
        DP
BCity   CP
```

I've tried several things but I cannot get it to work properly. I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Why are you storing city name in the project table ? Why not city `id` ? Even though you have normalized the tables, but are not using it effectively.

Comment: @Madhur There is actually a reason for it, having to do with duplicate city names across regions, etc ... legacy system that was modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/KZUOQC69270)**

```
SELECT *
FROM Projects P
LEFT JOIN (SELECT city, COUNT(city) as top_city
           FROM Projects
           WHERE type = 0
           GROUP BY city) R
  ON P.city = R.city
ORDER BY R.top_city DESC, 
         P.city, 
         P.type, 
         P.name
```

**OUTPUT:** I include all columns for debug, but you can limit your result to P.City and P.Name

[image]